# Angular component model with inferred conditional types

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular component my team is using for dropdowns. The model can be the ID of the options. However, since IDs can be `number` or `string`, and we can have `multi=true`, we're currently using a model of something like `string | string[] | number | number[]`.

Now that we're trying to enable `strictTemplates: true`, we're running into issues.

Is it possible to use some generics trick to infer when `@Input() multi: boolean` is set to true? Or maybe there's some way to clarify when it should be a `number` vs a `string` that the model is returning? The component is already doing the right thing but I'd like to get typescript to play along.